# How to use begins_with in AWS DynamoDb js sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a use case to apply **begins_with** on the **primary sort key** of an AWS Dynamodb table,
I am able to query the table using begins_with key condition from the AWS Console,
I wish to achieve the same using the AWS Javascript SDK.

[image]
[image]

**I have the following fields in my table -**
1. user_id (**Primary partition key**)
2. user_relation (**Primary sort key**)

**I tried the following code -**

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let util = require('util');

AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

let connection = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

let params = {
    TableName: 'user_details',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'user_id = :user_id and user_relation begins_with :user_relation',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':user_id': "1234",
        ':user_relation': "followed-by"
    }
};

console.log('getQuery Params => ', params);
let dynamoDb = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);
let results = await dynamoDb(params);
console.log('results => ', results);
```

I am getting a syntax error, what is the correct way to use **begins_with** while querying an AWS DynamoDb table?

**Error -**

```
(node:40474) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "begins_with", near: "user_relation BE
GINS_WITH :user_relation"
```

**References -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property
[DynamoDB,how to query with BEGINS_WITH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528932/dynamodb-how-to-query-with-begins-with)
[Can't Query DynamoDB with Begins_with for list of Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543319/cant-query-dynamodb-with-begins-with-for-list-of-items)

Comment: Where are you getting the Syntax error, can you post the error as well?

Comment: @uday8486 added the error

Comment: `user_id = :user_id and begins_with(user_relation, :user_relation)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try :

```
const params = {
  TableName: 'user_details',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#user_id = :user_id and begins_with(#user_relation, :user_relation)',
  ExpressionAttributeNames:{
    "#user_id": "user_id",
    "#user_relation": 'user_relation'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":user_id": "1234",
    ":user_relation": "followed-by"
  }
}
```

Comment: getting (node:40537) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "begins_with", near: "#user_relation b
egins_with :user_relation"

Comment: Updated the answer, tested it. It works. begins_with is a function, called like `begins_with(#user_relation, :user_relation)`

Comment: Wondering why we need all these extra properties. All of that information fits inside `KeyConditionExpress`, can we not put it all there? `ExpressionAttributeNames`, and `ExpressionAttributeValues` are just name fluff. This could be so much simpler : (